# How do I make a div (menu) fixed positioned after some scrolling has happened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a theme for a website and I was given permission to play with the HTML files. The thing is I'm just familiarised with CSS and HTML, but I'm a complete noob when it comes to Javascript, JQuery, etc. and, sadly, it seems I need those to add some features I want.

I'd like a menu that works like this one: https://www.planetside2.com/news

The HTML is basically this:

```
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="page-header">
  <div class="headerbar">
 </div>
</div>
```

And plenty stuff inside, but I hope the containers are enough

This is the CSS:

```
#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

.headerbar {
    background: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/headerbarbg.png") no-repeat ;
    background-position: center;
    width: 1054px;
    margin:0 -15px;
    margin-top:3px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

I've checked out some other solutions, but, as I said, I'm a complete noob at scripting and when I try to apply such scripts to the theme, they don't work, most likely because there are some things that I should change that I don't know (except classes and IDs, of course).

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: add position:fixed in css

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: That alone won't do it. The menu I want this on isn't at the very top of the website. It's like 73 px from it.

Comment: You can implement it as css and js as you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to detect scrolling and window resize

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).on("scroll resize", function(e){

        var elem = $(".headerbar");

        // check if your header is visible by subtracting
        // the top offset of your div from the scrolltop distance
        if ((elem.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) <= 0 && elem.css("position") !== "fixed") {
            console.log("not visible");
            elem.css({
                position:"fixed",
                "z-index":"9999",
                top:"0px"
            });
        // check if your header height is greater or equal to the scrolltop distance
        } else if (elem.height() >= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            console.log("visible");
            elem.css({
                position:"relative"
            });
        }

    });

})
```

And here is a simple demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hLh33d3o/1/)

Comment: This is what happens when I applied your solution to my website: http://etrostruewowdesigncomplete.esy.es/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1

Comment: It was a z-index issue, I edited the above code. It should be fine now.

Comment: I made some adjustments and it works better now, but there's some stuttering that is caused by the else of your script.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. It was the height of the headerbar. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing i have done previously in fiddle just check this one out will help you to have a scratch.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var top_fixed;
    if ($('#header-con').length > 0)
    {
        top_fixed = $('#header-con').offset().top;
    }
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($('#header-con').length > 0)
        {
            $('#header-con').toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > top_fixed);

        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/o1r6242m/3/)**

Comment: It isn't quite working for me. The header's position becomes fixed immediately after any scrolling: http://etrostruewowdesigncomplete.esy.es/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1

Comment: the link isn't even loading

Comment: I was changing some stuff. You can try now.

Comment: The website is. Your solution, not completely.

Answer (score -1):

This short jquery code is what you need.
Tested and was working in a website i had develop lately.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
        $('#fixed-menu-top').css('position', 'fixed').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#fixed-menu-top').css('position', 'absolute').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Just edit the `ids` to yours ex `#fixed-menu-top` to `#wrap` or any `ids` in ypur mark up

[See website](http://paradigm-gem.com/teacherstogo/ucp-india-philippines/)

Comment: sorry I think they just mess up the site

Comment: We have the same code with @benjamin only different logic on how we come up. I dont know if my answer deserves a downvote. :(

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote you, but still, your solution isn't quite what I want. I want something like this:  https://www.planetside2.com/news